# Should I be removing /public/packs from gitignore (rails - webpacker - Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, webpacker

I recently had an issue loading pages that contained webpacker packs.

```
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804323+00:00 app[web.1]: [66341a26-d0f1-4020-bd85-495d199087df] ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find flavour.js in /app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804326+00:00 app[web.1]: 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804327+00:00 app[web.1]:    unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804329+00:00 app[web.1]: 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804331+00:00 app[web.1]: 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804332+00:00 app[web.1]: 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804334+00:00 app[web.1]: Your manifest contains:
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804335+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804337+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804338+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804578+00:00 app[web.1]: [66341a26-d0f1-4020-bd85-495d199087df]     1: <%= javascript_pack_tag("flavour") %>
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804580+00:00 app[web.1]: [66341a26-d0f1-4020-bd85-495d199087df]     2: <%= javascript_pack_tag("beans") %>
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804582+00:00 app[web.1]: [66341a26-d0f1-4020-bd85-495d199087df]     3: <%= javascript_pack_tag("roasterselector") %>
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804583+00:00 app[web.1]: [66341a26-d0f1-4020-bd85-495d199087df]     4: <%= javascript_pack_tag("styleselector") %>
2019-01-12T10:24:46.804636+00:00 app[web.1]: [66341a26-d0f1-4020-bd85-495d199087df]
```

I have tried a number of things to resolve it:

- Moved webpack-dev-server from devDependencies to Dependencies in `package.json`
- Set config.assets.compile = true
- ran `$ rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

None of these worked.

I finally removed `public/packs` from my `.gitignore` file and this has seemingly resolved it?

However is this the right thing to do?  My compressed push size has gone from 88mb to 222mb.

Interestingly I noticed that I have many variations of the packs in my public/packs folder. Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: webpacker just works out of the box with Rails, also in production on heroku. I'd suggest you to try out with a new app and then compare them

Comment: We're running into the same issue. Just including the precompiled output directory from dev does not seem like the definitive solution. Did you ever get this resolved in a better way?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well.

Answer (score 3):

Do `bundle exec rails webpacker:clobber` before commit.